# Pythonnet .NET 6

Tags: python, .net, .net-core, python.net

After hours of searching and trial and error, I finally decided to ask you guys for help.
As I'm trying to call some functions from a .NET 6 open source project from python, I installed python3.8.4 on my raspberry pi and managed to install the pythonnet 3.0.0 module.

my app.runtime.json is the following:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
   "tfm": "net6.0",
   "framework": {
    "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
    "version": "6.0.102"
    }
   }
}
```

and when I try to load the CLR like this:

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime

rt = get_coreclr("app.runtime.json")
set_runtime(rt)
import sys
```

I get the following error message:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [11], in 
> 1 from clr_loader import get_coreclr
> 2 from pythonnet import set_runtime
> ----> 4 rt = get_coreclr("app.runtime.json")
> 5 set_runtime(rt)
> 6 import sys
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clr_loader/**init**.py:42,
> in get_coreclr(runtime_config, dotnet_root, properties)
> 39 from .hostfxr import DotnetCoreRuntime
> 41 if dotnet_root is None:
> ---> 42     dotnet_root = find_dotnet_root()
> 44 impl = DotnetCoreRuntime(runtime_config=runtime_config, dotnet_root=dotnet_root)
> 45 if properties:
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clr_loader/util/find.py:22,
> in find_dotnet_root()
> 20 dotnet_path = shutil.which("dotnet")
> 21 if not dotnet_path:
> ---> 22     raise RuntimeError("Can not determine dotnet root")
> 24 try:
> 25     # Pypy does not provide os.readlink right now
> 26     if hasattr(os, "readlink"):
>
> RuntimeError: Can not determine dotnet root

I exported the path to my dotnet 6.0 sdk to PATH and when I use "dotnet --version" it prints out 6.0.102.

What can I possibly have done wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Epi

Comment: Have you tried using an earlier version of .net? Importing a .net 6 dll didn't work for me, but changing the target the net48 did.

Comment: people still use net48? :P